# Sending data from PC to Android via USB

Tags: eclipse, android-intent, arduino, serversocket, libusb

What would be the best option to send data from a laptop to a USB accessory incompatible Android powered device, in order to interface an Arduino with an Android phone?

Can socket programming be the optimum choice to send data via ADB to send dynamic sensor inputs via Arduino to Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a look at [AirDroid](http://www.airdroid.com/). The Android device becomes a server allowing you to access files and apps over local Wi-Fi including things like streaming media. Not sure if you can make it work with arbitrary data, but it might be worth a try.